# What alternatives have sockets programming tcp on c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, networking

Is it possible to program network clients and servers using only system functions open, read and write on linux c++?
What low level alternatives have sockets?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than those three.

You need to use `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `connect`, `accept`, and typically also use `select`, `poll` or platform specific/higher performance modern `epoll` (Linux) and `kqueue` (BSD)

Depending on the socket type, you may be fine with `read` and `write`, but you may need `sendto`, `recvfrom`

The only way you could conceivably use "only read and write" would be to have the inetd super server open the network ports for you and map the port to STDIN and STDOUT. Look into inetd if that is your objective. If you go that route, you don't even need `read` and `write` you can literally use `printf`. A program under inetd doesn't even need to know it is a network program.

Why not try a high level library?

Check out Boost.Asio

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: Good answer, though instead of suggesting "select" and "poll", it would be better to suggest "epoll", particularly for servers that need to scale to a large number of open connections.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAaronSafyan - That is good to know. I'm a bit out of date, and my knowledge is mostly cross-platform. I haven't written any significant network code in a few years now and never specifically for Linux. I'll add your suggestion though!

Comment: He doesn't need to use `send()` and `recv()`: he can use `read()` and `write().`

Comment: Actually I meant to include `sendto` and `recvfrom` (@EJP - this wasn't meant to be a restrictive list, but if he wants to do UDP read/write aren't really sufficient)

Comment: Actually I would like to know about low level network programming.
How sockets are implemented on linux? Do they use any other API system functions to open connections, send and receive messages?

Comment: fedya I've already answered that. All of the calls I listed above are actually kernel sys-calls, implemented by the OS. Those are the socket intrinsics. Google "Berkeley sockets" or "BSD Sockets" or "POSIX Sockets", though nowadays, Linux has innovated past the original Berkeley standard, so maybe just "Linux sockets" is adequate. Outside that, I recommend you buy the book "TCP/IP Sockets in C, Second Edition: Practical Guide for Programmers" or "UNIX Network Programming by W. Richard Stevens"

Comment: Thank you very much )
I only thought if there was a way to use ioctl or something like that to talk directly to network interface, without sockets )
I have already downloaded a pdf version of "TCP/IP sockets in C", it seems to be very good tutorial. Thank you once again )

Comment: ioctl can be used to do a lot of things, including operations on sockets, but it doesn't replace the socket API. ioctl is really a catchall of various manipulations on device descriptors.

Comment: There are ways to talk directly to the network interface. For example, Linux has an ethertap driver, used for directly "tapping into" the network layer, routing / injection of raw packets can be performed with it. (I used it to write a low level VPN driver by encrypting at the enthernet level). But I'm not sure why you'd want to use this for regular network programming. The socket API is relatively ideal for its purposes.